# Retornar un array de objetos json obtenido del ajax de una función a otra función

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

En la función **almacenarProformas** hay una variable **listaAcuerdosMarco** , la cual me obtiene un array de objetos JSON obtenidos de la función **listarUsuariosXEmpresa**. En esta función, ejecuto una función AJAX, la cual me devuelve un array de objetos JSON. Posteriormente, necesito retorna esta variable a la función **almacenarProformas**  para su procesamiento.

```js
function listarUsuariosXEmpresa(idEmpresa){
    var listaUsuariosXEmpresa = "";
    var datos = {
        'opcion' : 'listarUsuariosXEmpresa',
        'id_empresa' : idEmpresa
    };
    $.ajax({
        url:'../controlador/descargarProformas.php',
        type:'POST',
        data : datos,
        cache:false,
        success: function(response){
            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            listaUsuariosXEmpresa = data;                
        }
    });
     return listaUsuariosXEmpresa;    
}
```

Deseo retornar el **listaUsuariosXEmpresa** que será un array de objetos a la siguiente función:

```js
function almacenarProformas(){
  var listaAcuerdosMarco = listarAcuerdosMarco();
  var codigoLista = "";
  for(var i=0; i<listaAcuerdosMarco.lenght;i++){
    codigoLista = listaAcuerdosMarco[i].codigo;
    var data = {
      "opcion" : "almacenarProformas",
      "lista"  :  codigoLista
    }
    $.ajax({
          url: '../controlador/descargarProformas.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: datos,
          success:   function (response) {
              abrirModal(response);
          }
    });
  }
  
}
```

Comment: No puedes hacer return dentro del método `success` del ajax.

Comment: Intenté hacerlo por fuera, pero no me funciona tampoco.

Comment: Intenta usar promise o asyncawait [aquí mas información](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)

Comment: Porque ese ciclo for con peticiones ajax, no creo que te funcione si no usas promise o asyncawait.

Comment: Podrías pasar almacenarProFormas como callback a tu otra función, y almacenarProFormas recibiría como parámetro la data que regresa tu post request

Answer (score 0):

Como te comenté, no puedes utilizar regresar un valor desde el AJAX, por que estará regresando a la función que lo invocó, en este caso regresará en `success`, pero como es una llamada asíncrona, el return no va a esperar esa respuesta, si no que siempre te regresará null.

Entonces aquí entra la magia de `async/await`, [Esta es la documentación oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)

Lo que hice es que, fue que le pedí al DOM, que la función `async` tendrá llamadas asíncronas que habrá que esperar con `await`. Te hice un pequeño ejemplo con la API de GitHub, lleva esta idea a tus regla de negocio, con eso deberás resolver el problema de la asincronía.

Otra forma de hacerlo, es metiendo toda la lógica que procesará la respuesta del ajax dentro del `success` (A la vieja usanza)

Prueba con mi usuario: **asiurob**

```js
$( () => {

  const obtenerGitUser = async( user ) => {
    
    const response = $.ajax({
      
      url: `//api.github.com/users/${ user }`,
      method: 'GET',
      success: await function( res ){
        return res;
      }
    })
    return response;
  }

$( document ).on('click', 'button', async function(){

  const name = $('#name').val();
  const res = await obtenerGitUser( name );
  
  console.log( res );

})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name">
<button>Consultar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí otra soluciones, espero que te sirva.

```js
async function listarUsuarioxEmpresa(idEmpresa) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: '../controlador/descargarProformas.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      'opcion': 'listarUsuariosXEmpresa',
      'id_empresa': idEmpresa
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: await (res) => res
  })
}

async function almacenarProformas(idEmpresa) {
  const listarUsuariosXEmpresas = await listarUsuarioxEmpresa(idEmpresa);

  for(var i=0; i < listaAcuerdosMarco.lenght; i++){
    let codigo = listaAcuerdosMarco[i].codigo;

    $.ajax({
          url: '../controlador/descargarProformas.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            "opcion" : "almacenarProformas",
            "lista"  :  codigo
          },
          dataType: "json",
          success: await (response) => abrirModal(response)
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías retornar el response de la función ajax y tratarlo como una promesa claro está que lo que estás retornando es un [object deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) el cual tiene los métodos `then`, `catch` etc.

```js
function foo() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    type: 'GET'
  })
}

foo()
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

te recomiendo usar la API [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), usar la `fn` ajax de JQuery ya es obsoleto.